# Why does my custom UICollectionViewLayout throw an error when adding space between cells?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm making a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class for practice, essentially trying to reproduce the horizontal flow layout where cells are laid out horizontally infinitely.

Everything was working perfectly with my `prepare()` and `layoutAttributesForElements()`  functions looking like this:

```
override func prepare() {
    cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

    var frame = CGRect.zero

    for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(item) * width + CGFloat(item) * spacing, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        attributes.frame = frame
        cache.append(attributes)
    }
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

The problem arises when I try to add an inset of value `spacing` to the x coordinate in following line in `prepare()` so that the first cell in the collection view has a leftwards inset:

```
frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(item) * width + CGFloat(item) * spacing, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
```

As soon as I do, everything looks well and good until I try swiping through the collection view. The following exception is thrown:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: <NSIndexPath: 0x618000036060> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}'
```

Would someone please explain why this is happening? Is there an alternative way of achieving the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Apparently overriding `layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?` fixes the issue! But I have no idea why.