# Unable to resize cells with custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm currently trying to implement custom divider views in between each cell of my collection view. I found this answer online that adds the custom view in the inter-line spacing ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45609198/6901471)).

```
private let separatorDecorationView = "separator"

final class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        register(SeparatorView.self,
                 forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) ?? []
        let lineWidth = self.minimumLineSpacing

        var decorationAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

        // skip first cell
        for layoutAttribute in layoutAttributes where layoutAttribute.indexPath.item > 0 {
            let separatorAttribute = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: separatorDecorationView,
                                                                      with: layoutAttribute.indexPath)
            let cellFrame = layoutAttribute.frame
            separatorAttribute.frame = CGRect(x: cellFrame.origin.x,
                                              y: cellFrame.origin.y - lineWidth,
                                              width: cellFrame.size.width,
                                              height: lineWidth)
            separatorAttribute.zIndex = Int.max
            decorationAttributes.append(separatorAttribute)
        }

        return layoutAttributes + decorationAttributes
    }
}

private final class SeparatorView: UICollectionReusableView {
    private let imageView: UIImageView = {
        let iv = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "cell-divider"))
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        self.frame = layoutAttributes.frame
    }
}
```

This solution actually works, and I'm able to see the dividers. The problem arises, however, when the user clicks on one of the cells. The behavior I want is for the cell to expand to show more details when the cell is clicked. The way I'm implementing this is by keeping track of which `indexPath`s are selected, and returning a larger size if they are selected in `sizeForItemAt`. In `didSelectItemAt`, I reload the collection view. This approach works when I'm using the normal `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, but when I try using my custom flow layout (above), I get the following crash:

```
no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind: separator at path <NSIndexPath: 0xf75c5b66b8a0a8ab> {length = 2, path = 0 - 6}
```

I tried looking up solutions and found these two stack overflows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118330/why-does-my-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-throw-an-error-when-adding-space-betwe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39867325/ios-10-bug-uicollectionview-received-layout-attributes-for-a-cell-with-an-index) but none of the answers I tried seemed to work.

I tried:

1. Invalidating the layout when I reload the collection view.
2. Implementing a cache that I return from when I override `layoutAttributesForItem` in my custom layout.

Any help would be greatly appreciated at this point!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I had to overwrite two methods in my custom layout:

```
    override func layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind elementKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let layoutAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: elementKind,
                                                                with: indexPath)
        return layoutAttributes;
    }

    override func initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingDecorationElement(ofKind elementKind: String, at decorationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        let attributes = layoutAttributesForDecorationView(ofKind: elementKind,
                                                           at: decorationIndexPath)
        return attributes
    }
```

I also needed to keep the layout invalidation call when I reloaded the data.

```
collectionView.reloadData()
let context = collectionViewLayout.invalidationContext(forBoundsChange: bounds)
context.contentOffsetAdjustment = CGPoint.zero
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout(with: context)

layoutSubviews()
```